# Does this change match 3NF on northwind database?

Tags: database, database-normalization, 3nf, northwind

I'd like to make those tables match the Inmons 3NF approach (im working on northwind database):

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXSDA.png)

I noticed Address thing keeps repeating and its not kinda even atomic so i decided to put another table in diagram called "Address" like this:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IesKG.png)

Is this valid approach? 
As table Address stores all the addresses anyway can i share them for all other tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is valid and is definitely more normalized.

However, it is not in 3NF yet. Strictly speaking, for a table to be in 3NF, you must not have any non-key inter-dependencies. In your example, there are such dependencies, between city and country for example. So every time someone enters Paris, they also need to enter France. This could lead to anomalies if someone accidentally enters Paris, Germany. For 3NF you would have to create an additional City table, which stores cities and their respective countries. City would be the key, country a non-key attribute. Address table would have a foreign key to city. I omitted Postcode and Region for brevity, but they would also need to be included in normalization. So, to make this 3NF you'd need a few more entities.

This complexity is why Kimball's star schema is more popular than Inmon's 3NF approach...